# Listen to a topic continiously, fetch data, perform some basic cleansing

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-streams

I'm to build a Java based Kafka streaming application that will listen to a topic X continiously, fetch data, perform some basic cleansing and write to a Oracle database. The kafka cluster is outside my domain and have no ability to deploy any code or configurations in it.

What is the best way to design such a solution? I came across Kafka Streams but was confused as to if it can be used for 'Topic > Process > Topic' scenarios?

Comment: *write to a Oracle database* -- Using Kafka Connect, I hope?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I came accross Kafka Streams but was confused as to if it can be used for 'Topic > Process > Topic' scenarios?

Absolutely.

For example, excluding the "process" step, it's two lines outside of the configuration setup.

```
final StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder();
builder.stream("streams-plaintext-input").to("streams-pipe-output");
```

This code is straight from [the documentation](https://kafka.apache.org/21/documentation/streams/tutorial)

---

If you want to write to any database, you should [first check if there is a Kafka Connect plugin](https://www.confluent.io/hub/) to do that for you. Kafka Streams shouldn't really be used to read/write from/to external systems outside of Kafka, as it is latency-sensitive.

In your case, [the JDBC Sink Connector](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/kafka-connect-jdbc/index.html#connect-jdbc) would work well.

> The kafka cluster is outside my domain and have no ability to deploy any code or configurations in it.

Using either solution above, you don't need to, but you will need some machine with Java installed to run a continous Kafka Streams application and/or Kafka Connect worker.